# Bash: MySQL update TXT record goes wrong

Tags: bash

I made a Bash script which updates some DNS records for me (I'm quite new to Bash, so please be patient).

My new record looks like this:

```
NEW_TXT_CONTENT="v=spf1 a mx ip4:${NEW_IP} ~all"
```

But correct DNS TXT records should have quotes around it. So I modified my new record to:

```
NEW_TXT_CONTENT="\"v=spf1 a mx ip4:${NEW_IP} ~all\""
```

The MySQL part looks like this:

```
mysql -u root -pPassword dnszones -e "UPDATE records SET content=\"${NEW_TXT_CONTENT}\" WHERE id=\"${TXT_ID}\""
```

I get following error code:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'v=spf1 a mx ip4:10.10.10.10 ~all"" WHERE id="27591"' at line 1
```

It looks like the database receives wrong quotes.

Is there another way to escape quotes?

**UPDATE**

I found out if I write my variable like this

```
NEW_TXT_CONTENT="'v=spf1 a mx ip4:${NEW_IP} ~all'"
```

it work's with writing in the database. But I don't want to use single-quotes.
If I make it vice versa, the variable `${NEW_IP}` won't be interpreted. Is there an easy solution?

Comment: How many quotes do you want? Run the following in a terminal and take a good look at the output: `x="\"x\"" ; echo "\"$x\""`

Comment: Looks like you're adding double quote twice in `NEW_TXT_CONTENT="\"v=spf1 a mx ip4:${NEW_IP} ~all\""` and `content=\"${NEW_TXT_CONTENT}\"`. Remove one...

Comment: Well. Not really working. If I remove (anywhere) a pair of double-quotes, it doesn't write it into the database with quotes at all: `v=spf1 a mx ip4:185.134.164.51 ~all`. It should write it like this: `"v=spf1 a mx ip4:185.134.164.51 ~all"`

Comment: @MattBackslash Wait, you want to *write the quotes to the database*? Then you can't use the same type of qoutes to quote the string. How would MySQL know which ones are which? This isn't so much a Bash question as a question about how to put quotes in a string in MySQL's syntax.